# How can I fix below sonarqube issue

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

Please check the below screenshot. I was able to fix all the other issues using try-with-resources. But I'm confusing how to fix this using try-with-resources.

[image]

Comment: *"Please check the below screenshot."* - Nope.  Instead, you need to [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) ... and fix your question.  Otherwise it is liable to be closed without an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it supposed to be done like following

```java
try (Connection con = client.getConnection();
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(...)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do I need to import Statement for this because eclipse shows different options

Comment: @thusila yes, you do